# Creating sub domain on webmin

Tags: subdomain, webmin

Can anybody help me in creating subdoain through webmin. I want to create subdomain like test.xxxxx.com for this I tried with several reference site but no luck.
exp.

http://www.trickylinux.net/add-domain-virtualminwebmin.html

http://codeboxlabs.com/add-subdomain-webmin-linux/

My current httpd.conf look like:

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
SSLEngine off 
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/******/web
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/*****/web">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName www.******.com
ServerAlias ftp.*****.com
SSLEngine off 
SSLVerifyClient optional
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: [check this link](http://howto.computerfoxdesign.com/entry.php?id=587)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know its been a year and you must have found a path already but its for the future reference.

Just add another host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/******/subdomain
DirectoryIndex index.php
<Directory "/var/www/html/*****/subdomain">
AllowOverride All
Allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName www.subdomain.******.com
ServerAlias subdomain.******.com
SSLEngine off 
SSLVerifyClient optional
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course restarting apache is needed in order to make it read the new VHost

What you need to do next is add an  **A record** in you domain registrar (i.e, Godaddy). Record name will be your "subdomain" and it'll point to your server address:

```
A-----------------> @ --------------------> ******.com
A-----------------> ******.com------------> ******.com
A-----------------> subdomian.******.com--> ******.com
```